# Ошибка при записи в первую строку csv

Tags: python

```
with open('file.csv', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.seek(0)
    file.write('text,text,text\n')
```

Когда пытаюсь прописать заголовки в csv файл у меня первую строку обрезает, что то вроде (было text стало xt)
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А если вместо `'r+'` указать `'w'`?

Comment: в таком случае удаляется содержимое файла, а если использовать `a` то записывает в конец файла

Comment: Вы хотите переписать первую строку файла, верно? А строки в файле оканчиваются на `\n` или `\r\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение по замене первой строки нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947384/5909792).

Пример:

```
import shutil

from_file = open("file.csv", encoding='utf-8')
line = from_file.readline()
line = 'text,text,text\n'

to_file = open("file.csv", mode="w", encoding='utf-8')
to_file.write(line)
shutil.copyfileobj(from_file, to_file)
```